# Linux search over HTTP

Tags: gratis, linux, web-apps, self-hosted, file-search

I'm running a server on Windows right now, and I use [Everything Search Engine](https://www.voidtools.com/) to allow users to [search through files over HTTP](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/http/).

I'm attending to upgrade the server to Linux, and I'm looking for an alternative.

I'm looking for a free program that will allow me to search through a folder (preferably using some indexing for speed) over HTTP. Bonus points for easy customization of the page displayed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: With "over HTTP", you mean that it should be a Web app, right? Or should/could it be a desktop client?

Comment: @unor A web app. I have mac and windows users, and it much easier to get compatibility this way.